# Divs se amontoando

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer um grid com 4 divs de 25% de width, mas elas não estao se despondo corretamente, quem poderá me salvar? já perdi horas e horas nisso!
HTML DA PARTE:





                    Compre agora seu certificado com cartão de crédito e emita ainda hoje!*

1
                    2
                    3
                    4

-->
CSS
.certificadocol1{

```
width: :25%;
height: 100px;
float: left;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 16px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
```

}
}
.certificadocol2{

```
width: :25%;
height: 100px;
float: left;
padding: 15px;  
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 16px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
```

}
}
.certificadocol3{

```
width: :25%;
float: left;
height: 100px;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 16px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
```

}
}
.certificadocol4{

```
width: :25%;
height: 100px;
float: left;
padding: 15px;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar dessa maneira https://jsfiddle.net/hbm9kvkn/